# php: path with include issue. can't reach file from two pages

Tags: php

I'm trying to reach file like this:

```
index.php
php/page.php
xml/file.xml
```

index.php:`<? include 'php/page.php'; ?>`
page.php: `<? $xml = simplexml_load_file("xml/file.xml"); ?>`

this works fine if i open `index.php`. but if I open `page.php`, error will shown. "can't find file `php/xml/file.xml`  "

I know I can use `../` but it will works fine in `page.php` not in `index.php`
any idea how i can fix it? (make it works fine from both pages)
Thanx
**Regards**

Comment: Well, it's due to the path being right when that is run from index... Since it's relative to index, and not when run from page. Solution? Test for which one and select a path, OR use an absolute path. Absolute would fix it most easily.

Comment: +1 for this. I think of it. but searching for another way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to eliminate that problem is use relative path from point where xml is included. So in page.php paste:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file(__DIR__.'/../xml/file.xml');
```

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't aware that `<? include 'page.php'; ?>` should work in `index.php` as the file is in a folder below.

If that is the case it seems the `include` function may check child directories if it fails to find the file. Assuming that's the case, `page.php` will not be able to find `file.xml` as it is not below it in the tree but is in fact a sibling. The function cannot start randomly traversing your file structure as it may find and include a different file by the same name which you did not intend.

*Edit*

Updated code makes more sense. Your includes are looking for folders within the current folder. `<? $xml = simplexml_load_file("xml/file.xml"); ?>` is looking for a folder called `xml` in the folder `php` because that is where it is being called from. What you need is `<? $xml = simplexml_load_file("/xml/file.xml"); ?>` which looks for a folder called `xml` in the root, notice the addition of the `/`.

Comment: Php has an 'include path': http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path

Comment: It's php/page.php. I changed it. But how I can reach file.xml from both pages

Comment: does not work but 'ziollek' answered. Thank you for all explanation :)